# Robot FW : Builtin library : "Pass Execution" keyword

Tags: robotframework, built-in

Referring to the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Variables)

> When used in any setup or teardown (suite, test or keyword), passes that setup or teardown. Possible keyword teardowns of the started keywords are executed. Does not affect execution or statuses otherwise.

Could you elaborate with simple examples what the above statement mean?

Comment: On [so] a certain amount of effort is expected to resolve your technical issue. Your question does not provide any code, nor any description of your observations of the error or outcome of your code. Both are expected as part of a good description and [mcve]. In it's current form your question does not meet the minimum requirements.

Comment: The official builtin library documentation lacks examples on the issue. I was unable to create an example of my own. The very reason for this thread is to get some examples.

Comment: Again, not a technical problem, which is what [so] focuses on. There is a certain amount of research expected from the person posting the question and that includes some experimentation. This would result in non-working code and results that you can then provide in the question. In it's current form your question appears that you didn't do this and are asking for working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Means that if you use on a suite, test or keyword, all the code after `Pass Execution` will not be called.

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup       Setup
Suite Teardown    Teardown

*** Keywords ***
Setup
    Pass Execution    Setup passed
    Log to Console    Setup

Teardown
    Pass Execution    Teardown passed
    Log to Console    Teardown
*** Test Cases ***

Keyword1
    Pass Execution    Keyword1 passed
    Log    Test
```

`Pass Execution` works like a `return` in python, making the keyword, testcase, teardown or setup exit with PASS. Try to comment `Pass Execution, then you can see the remaining code being executed

Comment: The documentation mentions the use of "Pass Execution" keyword in (suite, test or keyword) setup and teardown. Your example does not provide an example to those. Also, the keyword can be used in keyword teardowns, which i dont understand.